# Group folders by whether their names are alphabetical or numeric

Tags: c#

I want to group folders depending on their names. I do not want to move them into separate folders or change anything in the directory. Just for the cleaner display purpose I want to group them broadly into two folders. Folder Names as Alpha and Numeric.

Currently my code is fetching all folder names and their size along with total Size. So functionality remains same but instead of listing all folder I want to group then and show something like this-

```
Total size: xx.xx MB
Name: Alpa
Size: xx.xx MB
Name: Numb
Size: xx.xx MB
```

I would appreciate your suggestions on making this code more better.

Below is the code I am using.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"D\temp");

    long sizeOnDisk = DiskSize(dir, true);
    Console.WriteLine("Total Size: " + "{0:N2} MB", ((double)sizeOnDisk) / (1024 * 1024));


    foreach (DirectoryInfo folder in dir.EnumerateDirectories())
    {
        long sizeOfFolder = DiskSize(folder, true);

        Console.WriteLine("Name: " + "{0}", folder.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("Size: " +  "{0:N2} MB", ((double)sizeOfFolder) / (1024 * 1024));

    }
        Console.ReadLine();
}

static long DiskSize(DirectoryInfo dir, bool includeSubDir)
{

    long totalSize = dir.EnumerateFiles()
                 .Sum(file => file.Length);


    if (includeSubDir)
    {

        totalSize += dir.EnumerateDirectories()
                 .Sum(dirt => DiskSize(dirt, true));
    }
    return totalSize;
}
```

Comment: You have not actually asked a question here.

Comment: Ya, may be my way of asking was not correct. Basically I wanted advice on how would I make this code more better, best practice kind of.

Comment: "Best practice" questions are offtopic for stackoverflow.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Grab the first character of your directory name and use Parse on it.  Then you know what folder total to add the size to.

```
string firstChar = "1"; //or whatever the first character of your folder name is
            int num;
            if (Int32.TryParse(firstChar,num))
                NumbFolderSize += dir.Size;
            else
                AlpaFolderSize += dir.Size;
```

Comment: Thanks ! Yes I applied similar logic and separated the folders

Comment: Glad you figured it out!  Seems like people are addicted to downvoting on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming (since you didn't ask directly) that you want to group folders whose names are actually numbers vs those with non-numeric names, you can use a `GroupBy` operation with an appropriate key generation method to do so.

The simple test for a numeric filename is to use one of the `TryParse` methods.  Just in case you have very large numbers I would use `long.TryParse` to figure out whether or not the name is a number.  So you can create your groups like this:

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\Temp");
long v;
var folderGroups = dir.EnumerateDirectories().GroupBy(d =>
    long.TryParse(d.Name, out v) ? "Number" : "Alpha"
);
```

That will give you a set of `DirectoryInfo` records grouped by a `String` key.  Now you just need to get the sizes.  Instead of a recursive method that walks through the folder tree you can get a full list of all files in the tree in one call, sum the results and produce a sequence you can enumerate over like this:

```
var groupSizes = folderGroups
    .OrderBy(grp => grp.Key)
    .Select(grp => 
        new { 
            Name = grp.Key, 
            Size = grp.Sum(d => 
                // this is the bit that gets all of the files
                d.EnumerateFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                    .Sum(f => f.Length)) 
        }
    )
    .ToArray();
```

We can sum the above to get a total then add it back as a separate record, giving you an array of results that you can output in one loop:

```
var results = new[] { new { Name = "Total", Size = groupSizes.Sum(grp => grp.Size) } }
    .Concat(groupSizes);

foreach (var row in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", row.Name);
    Console.WriteLine("Size: {0:#,0.00} MB", row.Size / 1048576d);
}
```

Which on my test produces:

```
Name: Total
Size: 795.09 MB
Name: Alpha
Size: 137.46 MB
Name: Number
Size: 657.63 MB
```

Close enough?

Comment: Thanks for your response, I would try this out. You explained it well. I am a beginner so it is sometimes difficult for me to figure out what to apply where and how. Even though I have concepts.

Comment: I tend to use LINQ now a lot more than I used to, largely to get away from having to work with intermediate lists and such.  Being able to group and sort with a single method invocation does tend to simplify a lot of things, and once you get used to reading it LINQ queries can make it a lot simpler to understand what the code is doing... as long as you understand delayed execution.

Comment: I tried to run this code but for some reason I am only getting the top result ie. Name: Total